# not displaying json data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    $(document.ready(){

    var lookup = {
    "shared_items": 
       [{"entity_id":"253","position":1}, {"entity_id":"823","position":2}]
    }
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
     cache:false,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: "json",
     data: '{"name":"jonas"}',
     success: function(data) {$("#result").html(data.name) },
     }
   });

   });
```

I am new to ajax this is my first example towards can any one help me out.I want to pass json data `{"name":"jonas"}` and display it .

Comment: i dont know what are you trying..

Comment: The missing URL means it submits to itself.  Is there code on that page to return JSON data back?

Comment: have a look at this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: you can practice jQuery ajax with jQuery-mockjax (https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax)

Comment: Where is your PHP , aSp.NeT code to process ajax calls?

Answer (score 0):

`Ajax` is a group of programming techniques that make asynchronous calls to other pages

> without interfering with the display and the behavior of the existing
>   page (from [Wikipedia, Ajax Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)))

Data can be sent via `GET` or `POST` methods and retrieved as `jqXHR` a superset of browser `XHR` object. You can therefore use methods like `getResponseHeader()`.

If you want to pass to `ajaxexample.php` this array `{"name":"Jonas"}` your JavaScript code will be

```
$.ajax({
type: GET //The method, either POST or GET
url: 'ajaxexample.php', //The page you call
data: {name:"Jonas"}, //Array automatically converted in string with jQuery.param(). You can also use directly the string 'name=Jonas'
})
.done(function( data ) {
    //Do something with result data
});
```

If your page returns a `json` object you can use instead

```
$.getJSON({ "ajaxexample.php?name=Jonas", //Passed parameters appended to URL
function (data) {
    var message = data.message //Call to a json array element through its name (here 'message')
} 
});
```

A trivial version of ajaxexample.php code written in PHP can be (if you want to return json encoded data)

```
$msg = "Hello " . $_GET["name"]; //Retrieves sent data
$resArray = array("message" => $msg); //Creates an array with return values
json_encode($resArray); //Passes it with valid json sintax
```